# How do I make a quiz become graded via combo box results c#

Tags: c#, math, combobox

Hi so I'm just making a little tiny quiz and I was just wondering how I would calculate my score from the selected results in a combo box. I tried this and to test to see what my answer was I just displayed a messagebox, but the answer always turns out to be 0.

```
      private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox7.SelectedIndex == 2) //1
        {
            score1 = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            score1 = 0;
        }
        if (ComboBox8.SelectedIndex == 1)  //2
        {
            score2 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            score2 = 0;
        }
        if (ComboBox9.SelectedIndex == 2) //3
        {
            score3 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            score3 = 0;
        }
        if (ComboBox10.SelectedIndex == 0) //4
        {
            score4 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            score4 = 0;
        }
        if (ComboBox11.SelectedIndex == 0) //5
        {
            score5 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            score5 = 0;
        }
        int scores;
        int finalgrade;
        scores = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5;
        finalgrade = scores / 6;
        MessageBox.Show(finalgrade.ToString());


    }
```

If anyone could help me it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max score can be is 5, and since this is smaller than 6. 5/6 will always be 0 in integer division.

Comment: Oh oops i made a counting error. I changed it back to 5...So should i change finalgrade to a 'double'?

Comment: actually, even changing it to a double gives me 0

Comment: you should do something like this: double finalgrade = scores / 6.0

Comment: Oh okay what i did was finalgrade = (scores / 5.0)*100; so that i could get the actual percentage value. Thank you!